# IIS 10.0 access to aspx page throws 404 if the URL contains "end" keyword

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I have an IIS based web application. When I try to access LogOn.aspx page and the url contains "end" word the IIS throws 404.

for example if I try to access following URL

`http://myiisserver/mysite/LogOn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsite%2fend`

I get 404

If I replace "end" with "ent" it loads the login page

`http://myiisserver/mysite/LogOn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsite%2fent`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Have added Request Filtering rule for SQL injection which contains end keyword